# Combine number of lines of more files with filename

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

Specify a command / command set that displays the number of lines of code in the .c and .h files in the current directory, displaying each file in alphabetical order followed by ":" and the number of lines in the files, and finally the total of the lines of code.
An example that might be displayed would be :

```
test.c: 202
example.c: 124
example.h: 43
Total: 369
```

I'd like to find a solution in the shortest form possible. I've experimented many commands like:

1. `find . -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' | xargs wc -l`
   == it shows  `0 ./path/test.c` and the total, but isn't close enough
2. `stat -c "%n:%s" *`
   == it shows `test.c:0`, but it shows all file types and doesn't show the number of lines or the total
3. `wc -l *.c *.h | tr ' ' '\:`
   == it shows `0:test.c` and the total, but doesn't search in sub-directories and the order is reversed compared to the problem (`filename: number_of_lines`).

This one is closer to the answer but I'm out of ideas after searching most commands I saw in similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
wc -l *.c *.h | awk '{print $2 ": " $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a subshell in `xargs`

```
xargs -n1 sh -c 'printf "%s: %s\n" "$1" "$(wc -l <"$1")"' --
xargs -n1 sh -c 'echo "$1 $(wc -l <"$1")"' --
```